# 2 custom combo boxes, filter results in DataTables, issue getting 2 combo boxes to filter results - JavaScript, jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

I am tasked with creating a Datatable page with two customized combo boxes. Unfortunately, there isn't flexibility with this and they have to be customized, yet must correspond to their respective columns. I am having trouble getting these two combo boxes to filter results below.  I know my code is wrong, but it's where I'm at right now. Just for clarity, I want the ability to use both combo boxes simultaneously to filter results (example: show only project managers in London).

**HTML**

```
 <select id="dropdown1">
    <option value="">Select Position</option>
    <option value="Investigator">Investigator</option>
    <option value="Project Manager">Project Manager</option>
    <option value="Data Analyst">Data Analyst</option>
    <option value="Data Manager">Data Manager</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
    </select>

<select id="dropdown2">
    <option value="">Select Office</option>
    <option value="London">London</option>
    <option value="San Francisco">San Francisco</option>
    </select>

<br>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>Investigator</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Investigator</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Project Manager, Data Analyst</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Data Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>22</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jim Kelly</td>
                <td>Investigator, other</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>22</td>
            </tr>
              </tbody>
    </table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Qlfrtip'});

     $('#dropdown1').on('change', function () {
                    table.columns(1).search( this.value ).draw();
                } );
                $('#dropdown2').on('change', function () {
                    table.columns(2).search( this.value ).draw();
                } );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are calling `table.columns().search( this.value ).draw();` within your jQuery events, but you never initialized the table variable.

To fix this, change `$('#example').DataTable` inside of your `$(document).ready(function() {` to `var table = $('#example').DataTable`

See this working example:

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Qlfrtip'
        });

     $('#dropdown1').on('change', function () {
                    table.columns(1).search( this.value ).draw();
                } );
                $('#dropdown2').on('change', function () {
                    table.columns(2).search( this.value ).draw();
                } );
});
```

```html
<head>
<!--Styles-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/autofill/2.3.7/css/autoFill.dataTables.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.0.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/datetime/1.1.1/css/dataTables.dateTime.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/keytable/2.6.4/css/keyTable.dataTables.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.9/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowgroup/1.1.3/css/rowGroup.dataTables.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.3/css/select.dataTables.min.css"/>
        <!--Scripts-->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/autofill/2.3.7/js/dataTables.autoFill.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.0.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.0.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/datetime/1.1.1/js/dataTables.dateTime.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/keytable/2.6.4/js/dataTables.keyTable.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.9/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowgroup/1.1.3/js/dataTables.rowGroup.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.3/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<select id="dropdown1">
    <option value="">Select Position</option>
    <option value="Investigator">Investigator</option>
    <option value="Project Manager">Project Manager</option>
    <option value="Data Analyst">Data Analyst</option>
    <option value="Data Manager">Data Manager</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
    </select>

<select id="dropdown2">
    <option value="">Select Office</option>
    <option value="London">London</option>
    <option value="San Francisco">San Francisco</option>
    </select>

<br>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>Investigator</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Investigator</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Project Manager, Data Analyst</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Data Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>22</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jim Kelly</td>
                <td>Investigator, other</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>22</td>
            </tr>
              </tbody>
    </table>
```